# Rails & ActiveRecord Complex Query. Sorting based on child objects IF those child objects exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models: User, Event, and UserEvent.

```
class Event
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :users :through => :user_events
end

class User
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :events, :through => :user_events
end
```

A `UserEvent` has 3 columns: `user_id`, `event_id`, and `relevance` (float). `Relevance` is calculated in a background job for each user every hour. Each user should have exactly one UserEvent for every Event.

On my Events index page, I want to display a list of events ordered by their relevance to that particular user.

```
Event.includes(:event_rankings)
  .where("event_rankings.user_id = ?", current_user.id)
  .order("event_rankings.relevance DESC")
```

The issue I'm facing is that when a user visits the events index page immediately after signing up, the above query will return 0 results because that user has no UserEvents until the background job runs. But without the "where" clause, it will return irrelevant UserEvents from other users.

Is there a way to structure this query so that it sorts by a user's user_events.relevance IF they exist, but otherwise sort by date? I suppose a simple way would be an if/else which performs different queries but I'm wondering if there's one query that does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
Event.includes(:event_rankings)
  .where("event_rankings.user_id = ?", current_user.id)
  .order("event_rankings.#{event_rankings.relevance.empty? ? "date" : "relevance"} DESC")
```

I'm using a string interpolation with a conditional. So if `relevance` is empty, then it will call `order("event_rankings.date DESC")`, if not, it will call `order(event_rankings.relevance DESC")`